# Button doesn't show after document.write

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a rock, paper, scissors game and in the program, I have a button that should come up but it never does, It keeps giving me an error that says, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null". And if I get rid of the last "if" statement, it shows up but then disappears after it is clicked once.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Rock, paper, scissors game</title>
    <script>
    function game(){ 
        var userChoice= prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?");
        document.write("You chose " + userChoice + ". <br/>")
        var computerChoice= Math.random();
        if(computerChoice<=0.33){
            computerChoice="rock";
        }
        else if(computerChoice<=0.67){
            computerChoice="paper";
        }
        else{
            computerChoice="scissors";
        }
        document.write("The computer chose " + computerChoice + ". <br/>");
        if(userChoice==computerChoice){
            document.write("TIE!!!!");
        }
        if(userChoice=="paper" && computerChoice=="rock"){
            document.write('<p style="color:red">You win!</p>');
        }
        if(userChoice=="rock" && computerChoice=="scissors"){
            document.write('<p style="color:red">You win!</p>');
        }
        if(userChoice=="scissors" && computerChoice=="paper"){
            document.write('<p style="color:red">You win!</p>');
        }
        if(userChoice=="scissors" && computerChoice=="rock"){
            document.write('Sorry, you lose.');
        }
        if(userChoice=="rock" && computerChoice=="paper"){
            document.write("Sorry, you lose.");
        }
        if(userChoice=="paper" && computerChoice=="scissors"){
            document.write("Sorry, you lose.");
        }
        if(userChoice=="Chuck Norris"){
            document.write("This program bows down to your superiority, YOU WIN!!!!");
        }
        if(document.getElementById("buttonclick").style.display == "none"){
            document.getElementById("buttonclick").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="game()">
    <button type="button" style="display:none;" id="buttonclick" onclick="game()">Play Again!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no button with id `buttonclick`

Comment: Also, document.write will overwrite the DOM.

Comment: Hello Arun, I fixed that just now. I made a mistake with the code formatting.

Comment: can u create sample of ur app in jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `document.write` will overwrite your entire DOM, so the button you initialized onload will actually be overwritten by the contents of your `document.write`.

However, if you do not want your content to disappear, I suggest making a new `div` and using `document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML` in place of your `document.write()` commands in order to save the button.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `document.write`, it will display its content by overwriting all the DOM elements.

So you need to use `innerHtml` for displaying the contents keeping your DOM Alive.